# Vnoremap function equivalent in Spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs

Is there a way to get something like

```
vnoremap <F3> :call Surround("prfx_", "_psfx")<Enter>
function! Surround(prefix, postfix)
    " get the selection
    let selection = @*
    " remove selected text
    normal gv"xx
    " inserting text with prefix and postfix
    execute "normal i" . a:prefix . selection . a:postfix
endfunction
```

In Spacemacs? I have this in my .vimrc and it would be incredibly handy to have the same functionality while working with .org files.  Is this something I will need to learn to implement in Elisp?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way. And yes it is something you will have to implement in elisp. I'm not 100% sure of what exactly your function does.

But you'll probably have to use:
`(evil-define-key '(visual) 'org-mode-map "<f3>" 'your-surround-function)`

Also look into packages like this: https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil-surround